# "select * from persons where user='username' and pass='password'" - why is this mysql statement boolean

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a beginner in PHP and MySQL.

I'm trying to create a basic site with users. Right now I'm creating the log in page, and I'm using the following two lines, where the `mysqli_fetch_array()` is just to see if there are any with user as `$_POST['user']` and pass as `$_POST['pass']`:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM persons WHERE user='" . $_POST['user'] . "' AND pass=ENCODE('" . $_POST['pass'] . "',passcode)");
while(mysqli_fetch_array($query)) // line 65
    // ..
```

When there is the error

> **Warning:** mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in **D:\xampp1.8.3\htdocs\hkmschat\default.php** on line **65**

*Why is this statement boolean?* I've used `mysqli_fetch_array()` and very similar queries many times for other verifications in the same script, but none of them have returned something like this.

I know there are a lot of these out there, but I haven't found one yet that has answered this question yet. If you could please redirect me to a good answer or answer this question, that would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `mysqli_error()` would tell you why.

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: **Danger**:  You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to learn how to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Type [php.net/mysqli](http://php.net/php.net/mysqli) in your browser, click on "Executing statements" and see any of the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is failing and returning a false value.

put this after your mysqli_query() to see whats going on.

```
if (!$query) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}
```

for more information.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

please always try to print the query, before executing

Comment: oh, it was a silly mistake - where it said `ENCODE('" . $_POST['pass'] . "','passcode')` i didn't put quotes around the `'passcode'`

Comment: gr8, then accept the answer , if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You should go about it like this:

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
   echo $res['user'];
   //Etc...
}
```

The code will return boolean if you don't set it to a variable.

The variable `$res[]` is an array with all the fields of the found row/s.

Furthermore you code is passible of SQL injections and therefore ***DANGEROUS***, see this article: [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)